# Not able to download truffle

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle

I am trying to download truffle by typing "npm install -g truffle" on windows 10 with the visual studio terminal  but i dont know why i get these messages. I already have installed NodeJS.

I apologise for my bad english.

```
PS C:\Users\lucae\Desktop\aaa> npm install -g truffle
```

npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated ipld-raw@6.0.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.

npm WARN deprecated cids@1.1.9: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-cbor@0.17.1: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-cbor and multiformats

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated @nodefactory/filsnap-adapter@0.2.2: Package is deprecated in favour of @chainsafe/filsnap-adapter

npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.
Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.
Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.
Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.2.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.

Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multibase@4.0.6: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multibase@3.1.2: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated ipld-dag-pb@0.20.0: This module has been superseded by @ipld/dag-pb and multiformats

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@3.2.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped
package will recieve updates in the future

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated multicodec@2.1.3: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated axios@0.20.0: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410

npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module

npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path C:\Users\lucae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1

npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\lucae\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32228.343) found at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.31019.35) found at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042

npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\lucae\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1

npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\lucae\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-14T09_56_50_681Z-debug-0.log

[warning][1]

[warning2][2]

[error1][3]

[error 2][4]

thx a lot for your help !

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k1g7.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNfVD.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkikc.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVTUb.png
```

edit :

I did the update of visual studio tools and downloaded the last version with c++ but i still have the same issue

Comment: What are your Inputparameters? Please provide more informations.

Comment: Oh yeah i forgot i edited, wich informations could i provide ?

Comment: Ahh I see this are links to screenshots. You could provide the code and errors as plain text, because i will not click any links ;) (even a imgur shortlink)

Comment: okay no problem i thought it would be more easy with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to install Visual Studio including the "Desktop development with C++".

From the logs

> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
>
> ---
>
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of
> Visual Studio
>
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++"
> workload.
>
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the
> documentation at:
>
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
>
> npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
>
> ---

Comment: Hello thx for ur help so now i got different errors i am looking on the net to see what could i do